# My Table Adds Page Breaks

Tags: formatting, tabularx

I am making a table and have two problems.  Here is the start of the TeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{center}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}

\hline

a  &  b  &  c  &  d  &  e  &  f   &  g  \\ \hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{landscape}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

My problems:

1. When I compile two blank pages get added to the PDF before the table appears.  I tried using \afterpage, but to no good effect.
2. I would like to add a title to the table.  Using \caption it will list the title on the first page, skip a page, then list the table.

Comment: I think you are missing part of your code...

Comment: @MarioS.E. I am only missing the data for the table itself.  That's why I say that this is how the TeX code "starts".

Comment: @Mico Doing that yields one extra page instead of two.

Comment: Enclosing `landscape` in `center` is the cause of your problems. Just issue `\centering` after `\begin{landscape}`. Roughly, what happens is that `\begin{landscape}` ends the paragraph to be centered, which is empty and is typeset on one page; then it starts the landscape page. If I remove the offending `center` environment and add a row to the table, closing `tabularx` and `landscape` I get exactly one landscape page.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126  It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  This way is easier to copy and paste the code and correct any errors we might find

Comment: @MarioS.E. This is for work.  I am not allowed to disclose the information in the table with anyone.  All I do is type the table entries and then close out the environments.

Comment: @egreg I still get the addition of a page after removing the \begin{center}.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 a minimal example doesn't need to be your _real_ data, but it should always be a complete document that shows the problem, you could just use `&a&b&c` and then finish off all the open environments if that is enough. Otherwise you can not really expect people to test their answers.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Perfect, do not disclose it.  That's why we use `foo` & `bar` expressions, `lorem lipsum` text, `blindtext` and all kind of text fillers to maintain confidentiality, clearly express our issues and at the same time make everything easier for those who are trying to help us :)

Comment: It has been edited to include a sample.

Comment: I've edited your example code to make it compilable: I changed `\end{tabular}` to `\end{tabularx}`, and I added `\end{center}` before `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

You can get rid of the blank page via one of two methods while ensuring that the contents of the `landscape` environment are centered:

- Exchange the order of the `center` and `landscape` environments, i.e., type something like

  ```
  ...
  \begin{landscape}
  \begin{center}
  ...
  \end{center}
  \end{landscape}
  ...
  ```
- Get rid of the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` statements entirely and insert the instruction

  ```
  \centering
  ```

  after `\begin{landscape}`.

You raise a separate question: How to add a "title" -- I assume you mean a caption -- to the table. To do that, encase the `tabularx` environment in a `table` environment and type

```
\caption{<Title of table>}
```

either before or after the `tabularx` environment -- but still inside the `table` environment, of course.

Comment: \begin{landscape} and \end{landscape} both clear any outstanding page: they're there to enable complete pages of landscape material, not to provide landscape boxes within a single portrait page -- the \rotatebox facilities in the graphics package deal with that requirement.

Comment: @wasteofspace - You write that the `landscape` environment isn't there to "to provide landscape boxes within a single portrait page". Is the purpose of this statement to refute something I wrote (but which I'm honestly not even aware of having written)? Or are you just providing supplemental information? Please advise.